# Pointer (memory) alignment to 16K in Swift for Metal buffer creation

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I'd like to createa Metal buffers with the [newBufferWithBytesNoCopy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLDevice_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MTLDevice/newBufferWithBytesNoCopy:length:options:deallocator:) function for letting CPU and GPU share memory and practicing zero-copy data transfer.

The newBufferWithBytesNoCopy function takes a UnsafeMutablePointer-type pointer, and the pointer needs to be aligned to 16K(16384) bytes.

Could anyone provide advice on how to create a aligned memory to a certain size in Swift?

Comment: I don't know anything about swift, but in general, you can allocate an extra 16k and round up as needed to find the next 16k boundary. If you know your system better you may be able to reduce the additional allocation size.

Comment: @mah Thanks for the advice. I am looking for something like alignas in C. I am using Accelerate Framework in Metal and use some of vDSP's API which is Objective-C where I have UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>. I'd like to know how to use alignas or something similar to it to allocate memory and assign it to the UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>. With my best attempt so far, I have not been able to find a good example for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently copying Swift Array to memory buffer for iOS Metal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317572/efficiently-copying-swift-array-to-memory-buffer-for-ios-metal)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this should work for you:

```
var memory:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> = nil
var alignment:UInt = 0x4000 // 16K aligned
var size:UInt = bufferSize // bufferSize == your buffer size

posix_memalign(&memory, alignment, size)
```

For reference:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_memalign.html

Comment: Comment from a NAA of Warren Stringer:  *Change UInt to Int for more recent versions of Swift.*

Answer (score 2):

### Swift PageAligned Array (just works solution)

[PageAlignedArray](https://github.com/eldade/PageAlignedArray) is a project that handles the problem of memory allocation for you when memory that will be used with Metal.

### More detail

#### 4096 byte alignment

I'm not seeing your 16k byte requirement. The debugger says 4k. Maybe you can provide a reference? It should be based upon the system's page size.

#### Using posix_memalign

The original idea came from [memkite](http://memkite.com/blog/2014/12/30/example-of-sharing-memory-between-gpu-and-cpu-with-swift-and-metal-for-ios8/) I believe and goes like this:

```
private func setupSharedMemoryWithSize(byteCount: Int) ->
    (pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>,
    memoryWrapper: COpaquePointer)
{
    let memoryAlignment = 0x1000 // 4096 bytes, 0x4000 would be 16k
    var memory: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> = nil
    posix_memalign(&memory, memoryAlignment, byteSizeWithAlignment(memoryAlignment, size: byteCount))

    let memoryWrapper = COpaquePointer(memory)

    return (memory, memoryWrapper)
}
```

#### Calculating the memory size

You'll want to calculate the correct amount of memory to allocate so that it lands on the byte boundary. Which means you'll probably need to allocate a bit more than you desired. Here you pass the size you need and alignment and it will return the amount you should allocate.

```
private func byteSizeWithAlignment(alignment: Int, size: Int) -> Int
{
    return Int(ceil(Float(size) / Float(alignment))) * alignment
}
```

#### Using the functions

```
let (pointer, memoryWrapper) = setupSharedMemoryWithSize(byteCount)
var unsafeVoidPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> = pointer

// Assuming your underlying data is unsigned 8-bit integers.
let unsafeMutablePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(memoryWrapper)
let unsafeMutableBufferPointer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: unsafeMutablePointer, count: byteCount)
```

Don't forget to free the memory you allocated.

### Allocating shared memory without posix_memalign.

These days you can allocate the memory without `posix_memalign` by just specifying .StorageModeShared.

```
let byteCount = 1000 * sizeof(Float)
let sharedMetalBuffer = self.metalDevice.newBufferWithLength(byteCount, options: .StorageModeShared)
```

Comment: _“so that it lands on the byte boundary.”_  Huh?  Isn't that precisely what `posix_memalign()` is for?  I don't understand what purpose `byteSizeWithAlignment()` serves— it makes perfect sense to use something like this if you were allocating memory with `malloc()`, but not with `posix_memalign()`.

Comment: You'd think that. However, with the unified memory architecture for CPU and GPU you must allocate memory such that you can access it from either and that can mean the CPU will accept a wider range of alignments than the GPU. That's why it is better to use newBufferWithLength()

Comment: Sure, yeah, I'll be using `newBufferWithLength()` for cases where it's viable _(e.g. Metal-only; not viable for Metal/OpenGL-compat code)_.  But back to my point of contention, why shouldn't I think that?  `byteSizeWithAlignment()` doesn't affect the start-address-returned-pointer alignment of the memory, only the amount memory.  If there's a doc somewhere that says Metal requires buffers to not only start page-aligned but also _fully fill even multiples of pages_, I'd like to read it.

Comment: I would have to try again, but as I recall it needs to be a multiple of the acceptable size AND start on the boundary.

Comment: Also FWIW, your `posix_memalign()` is invalid API usage.  The docs require that the `size` supplied needs to be a power of 2.

Comment: The address of the allocated memory will be a multiple of alignment, which must be a power of two and a multiple of sizeof(void *)

Comment: As far as my reading of posix_memalign, I don't see anything about the allocation needing to be a power of 2. The reference simply said, "the allocated memory will be a multiple of alignment, which must be a power of two and a multiple of sizeof(void *)". At the time if you had a non-multiple of the alignment it would fail.

Comment: Um wot? E.G. Given an alignment of 4096 bytes, allocating 12288 bytes would be a multiple of alignment, but would not be a power of 2.

Comment: Ha, okay then.  So I misread that— size has no Po2 requirements (for `posix_memalign`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139030/discussion-between-slipp-d-thompson-and-cameron-lowell-palmer).

Answer (score 1):

After experiencing some annoyance with this problem, I've decided to go ahead and create a simple solution that should make this a lot easier.

I've created a Swift array implementation called `PageAlignedArray` that matches the interface and functionality of the built-in Swift array, but always resides on page-aligned memory, and so can be very easily made into an `MTLBuffer`. I've also added a convenience method to directly convert `PageAlignedArray` into a Metal buffer.

Of course, you can continue to mutate your array afterwards and your updates will be automatically available to the GPU courtesy of the shared-memory architecture. However, keep in mind that **you must regenerate your `MTLBuffer` object whenever the array's length changes.**

Here's a quick code sample:

```
  var alignedArray : PageAlignedContiguousArray<matrix_double4x4> = [matrixTest, matrixTest]
  alignedArray.append(item)
  alignedArray.removeFirst() // Behaves just like a built-in array, with all convenience methods

  // When it's time to generate a Metal buffer:
  let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
  let testMetalBuffer = device?.makeBufferWithPageAlignedArray(alignedArray)
```

The sample uses `matrix_double4x4`, but the array should work for any Swift value types. Please note that if you use a reference type (such as any kind of `class`), the array will contain pointers to your elements and so won't be usable from your GPU code.

Please grab `PageAlignedArray` here: https://github.com/eldoogy/PageAlignedArray