# Efficiently copying Swift Array to memory buffer for iOS Metal

Tags: ios, swift, metal, swift-array

I am writing an iOS application using Apple's new Metal framework.   I have an array of Matrix4 objects (see [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81399/ios-8-metal-tutorial-swift-moving-to-3d)) that I need to pass in to a shader via the MTLDevice.newBufferWithLength() method.  The Matrix4 object is leveraging Apple's GLKit (it contains a GLKMatrix4 object).

I'm leveraging instancing with the GPU calls.

I will later change this to a struct which includes more data per instance (beyond just the Matrix4 object.

1. How can I efficiently copy the array of [Matrix4] objects into this buffer?
2. Is there a better way to do this?  Again, I'll expand this to use a struct with more data in the future.

Below is a subset of my code:

```
let sizeofMatrix4 = sizeof(Float) * Matrix4.numberofElements()

// This returns an array of [Matrix4] objects.
let boxArray = createBoxArray(parentModelViewMatrix)

let sizeOfUniformBuffer = boxArray.count * sizeOfMatrix4
var uniformBuffer = device.newBufferWithLength(sizeofUniformBuffer, options: .CPUCacheModeDefaultCache)
let bufferPointer = uniformBuffer?.contents()

// Ouch - way too slow.  How can I optimize?
for i in 0..<boxArray.count
{
    memcpy(bufferPointer! + (i * sizeOfMatrix4), boxArray[i].raw(), sizeOfMatrix4)
}

renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(uniformBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 2)
```

Note:
The boxArray[i].raw() method is defined as this in the Objective-C code:

```
- (void *)raw {
    return glkMatrix.m;
}
```

You can see I'm looping through each array object and then doing a memcpy.  I did this since I was experiencing problems treating the array as a contiguous set of memory.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be using simd.float4x4.

Answer (score 8):

A Swift Array is promised to be contiguous memory, but you need to make sure it's really a Swift Array and not secretly an NSArray. If you want to be completely certain, use a ContiguousArray. That will ensure contiguous memory even if the objects in it are bridgeable to ObjC. If you want even more control over the memory, look at `ManagedBuffer`.

With that, you should be using `newBufferWithBytesNoCopy(length:options:deallocator)` to create a MTL buffer around your existing memory.

Comment: Rob, thanks for the feedback.  I've been trying to work this out since you posted a response but simply am not having any luck.   Would you mind providing source code illustrating how you start with an array of [Matrix4] objects, create the MTLDevice buffer and then memcpy to that buffer?

Comment: Rob, do you think `ManagedBuffer` provides page-aligned storage? A cursory glance at the source code and the documentation suggests that this only enforces element alignment (by honoring `MemoryLayout<Element>.alignment`), not page alignment. Page alignment is potentially far more wasteful and so I'd expect to see it explicitly mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

I've done this with an array of particles that I pass to a compute shader.

In a nutshell, I define some constants and declare a handful of mutable pointers and a mutable buffer pointer:

```
let particleCount: Int = 1048576
var particlesMemory:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> = nil
let alignment:UInt = 0x4000
let particlesMemoryByteSize:UInt = UInt(1048576) * UInt(sizeof(Particle))
var particlesVoidPtr: COpaquePointer!
var particlesParticlePtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Particle>!

var particlesParticleBufferPtr: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Particle>!
```

When I set up the particles, I populate the pointers and use posix_memalign() to allocate the memory:

```
    posix_memalign(&particlesMemory, alignment, particlesMemoryByteSize)

    particlesVoidPtr = COpaquePointer(particlesMemory)
    particlesParticlePtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Particle>(particlesVoidPtr)

    particlesParticleBufferPtr = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: particlesParticlePtr, count: particleCount)
```

The loop to populate the particles is slightly different - I now loop over the buffer pointer:

```
    for index in particlesParticleBufferPtr.startIndex ..< particlesParticleBufferPtr.endIndex
    {
        [...]

        let particle = Particle(positionX: positionX, positionY: positionY, velocityX: velocityX, velocityY: velocityY)

        particlesParticleBufferPtr[index] = particle
    }
```

Inside the applyShader() function, I create a copy of the memory which is used as both the input and output buffer:

```
    let particlesBufferNoCopy = device.newBufferWithBytesNoCopy(particlesMemory, length: Int(particlesMemoryByteSize),
        options: nil, deallocator: nil)

    commandEncoder.setBuffer(particlesBufferNoCopy, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)

    commandEncoder.setBuffer(particlesBufferNoCopy, offset: 0, atIndex: 1)
```

...and after the shader has run, I put the shared memory (particlesMemory) back into the buffer pointer:

```
    particlesVoidPtr = COpaquePointer(particlesMemory)
    particlesParticlePtr = UnsafeMutablePointer(particlesVoidPtr)

    particlesParticleBufferPtr = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: particlesParticlePtr, count: particleCount)
```

There's an up to date Swift 2.0 version of this [at my GitHub repo here](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/MetalKit-Particles)

Comment: Can you outline the Swift 2 differences?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously the point of using shared memory and `MTLDevice.makeBuffer(bytesNoCopy:...)` is to avoid redundant memory copies. Therefore, ideally we look for a design that allows us to easily manipulate the data after it's already been loaded into the `MTLBuffer` object.

After researching this for a while, I've decided to try and create a semi-generic solution to allow for simplified allocation of page-aligned memory, loading your content into that memory, and subsequently manipulating your items in that shared memory block.

I've created a Swift array implementation called [`PageAlignedArray`](https://github.com/eldoogy/PageAlignedArray) that matches the interface and functionality of the built-in Swift array, but always resides on page-aligned memory, and so can be very easily made into an `MTLBuffer`. I've also added a convenience method to directly convert `PageAlignedArray` into a Metal buffer.

Of course, you can continue to mutate your array afterwards and your updates will be automatically available to the GPU courtesy of the shared-memory architecture. However, keep in mind that **you must regenerate your `MTLBuffer` object whenever the array's length changes.**

Here's a quick code sample:

```
  var alignedArray : PageAlignedContiguousArray<matrix_double4x4> = [matrixTest, matrixTest]
  alignedArray.append(item)
  alignedArray.removeFirst() // Behaves just like a built-in array, with all convenience methods

  // When it's time to generate a Metal buffer:
  let testMetalBuffer = device?.makeBufferWithPageAlignedArray(alignedArray)
```

The sample uses `matrix_double4x4`, but the array should work for any Swift value types. Please note that if you use a reference type (such as any kind of `class`), the array will contain pointers to your elements and so won't be usable from your GPU code.

Comment: Brilliant!!! Just a question - I was thinking of just creating a mutable array with the initializer that takes a mutable buffer pointer - did you consider this, and if so, why did you reject it?

Comment: @DavidH How would the array grow if set up in this manner? I had my own class do the allocation so as to allow the array to grow as needed.

Comment: Of course you are right. I was thinking of a fixed size mutable array but of course no way to prevent someone from trying too append. Again, great post!

Comment: How allocate all memory at once?
if I use native arrays I can call

`[Float](repeating: 0, count: 40_000_000)`

to allocate 160mb of ram at once

But with this library I have to run loop over 40_000_000 and append array. And this takes ~40sec